# i have errors in flutter even when working on a project with basic flutter

Tags: flutter

When I want to run the application this error appears
Even if it's a basic project for flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart(734,9): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'srethrow' isn't defined for the class 'AssetBundleImageProvider'. [C:\Users\410050\Desktop\flutter project\flutter_application_6\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\Users\410050\Desktop\flutter project\flutter_application_6\build\windows\CMakeFiles\dae9ac948ac073d852e44769c5547fe9\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\Users\410050\Desktop\flutter project\flutter_application_6\build\windows\CMakeFiles\3053275b8a6ec02e6b73a81dc9e8c24d\flutter_assemble.rule' exited with code 1. [C:\Users\410050\Desktop\flutter project\flutter_application_6\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
Exited (sigterm)

I updated the flutter to the latest version and did the flutter doctor, but there are no problems

Comment: Did you add images or anyother thing in assets?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [discussion](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62170#issuecomment-704425282) you need to replace`srethrow` to `rethrow` in `image_provider.dart`. You can find it on `Flutter/Sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart` . I've checked in my computer and I found `rethrow`, not `srethrow`.